# PHP adding months and days to the current time() and ovoid weekend days

Tags: php, unix-timestamp, strtotime

I need to add N months and M days to the current time() in PHP. My current solution is simple, but I was wondering can it be even simpler :)?

```
$my_time = strtotime("+6 days", strtotime("+1 month", time()));
```

I am also wondering if there is a chance to avoid weekends (Saturday and Sunday) in the target date?

Comment: strtotime("+6 days 1 month", time()); should do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can simplify it to:

```
$my_time = strtotime("+6 days 1 month", time());
```

Or:

```
$my_time = strtotime("+6 days 1 month");
```

See [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Comment: Ahh how was I able to miss this. I was hoping something like this would work and it does. Gr8, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) class, because it is much faster than strtotime.

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->add(new DateInterval('P1M6D'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Detailed synthax info for the DateInterval can be found [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php).

Answer (score 1):

*Try this following Methods*
**use strtotime() function add days months years**

**For Day add**
    date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+3 days"));
**For month add**

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+3 month"));
```

**year add**

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+3 year"));
```

**For day month year add**

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+1 days 1 month 1 year "));
```

**For subtract day month year**

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-1 days 1 month 1 year "));
```

just use (**+** and **-**) symbols